# Object of class CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter

Heres my controller :

```
public function create()
{
    session();
    $data = [
        'main' => 'prosescutting/create',
        'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
        'title' => 'Form Tambah Proses Cutting',
        'kodeunik' => $this->pcuttingModel->buat_kode()
    ];
    return view('template/template', $data);
}
```

Model :

```
public function buat_kode()   { 
    
    $query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting')
                        ->orderBy('kode_packing_list', 'DESC')
                        ->limit(1);
    // $kodemax = $kode;
    // $kodejadi = "PLIK059".$kodemax;
    return $query;
```

It show me errors **Object of class CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder could not be converted to string** the line that show was

`<td><input type="text" name='kode_packing_list' class="form-control" value="<?= $kodeunik; ?>" readonly></td>`

which is in my view/create.php

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Maybe you forgot to query the database, as `$query` is never executed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a result in CodeIgniter. Like so;

```
$result = $query->row_array(); // For single row as array
$result = $query->row(); // Single object

$result = $query->result_array(); // For multiple rows as array
$result = $query->result(); // For multiple rows as objects
```

Model:

```
public function buat_kode() { 
     $query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting')
                    ->orderBy('kode_packing_list', 'DESC')
                    ->limit(1);   
     $return = $query->row_array();
     return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with codeigniter 4. Do this to help you solve this issue

In your controller

```php
public function create()
{
    session();
    $data = [
        'main' => 'prosescutting/create',
        'validation' => \Config\Services::validation(),
        'title' => 'Form Tambah Proses Cutting',
        'kodeunik' => $this->pcuttingModel->buat_kode()
    ];
    return view('template/template', $data);
}
```

Model :

```php
public function buat_kode()   { 
    
    $query = $this->db->table('proses_cutting')
                        ->orderBy('kode_packing_list', 'DESC');
    // $kodemax = $kode;
    // $kodejadi = "PLIK059".$kodemax;
    return $query->get()->getRow();
```

Then since you are assigning object data fetch from the model to the array index `kodeunik`, call this as object on the view file like this `$kodeunik->what_column_name_you_are_calling_from_database;`

That is

```html
<td><input type="text" name='kode_packing_list' class="form-control" value="<?= $kodeunik->what_column_name_you_are_calling_from_database; ?>" readonly></td>
```

I hope this help you. If not call my attention. I am ready to help you